# Cannot delete corrupted SVN repository in VisualSVN Server

Tags: visualsvn-server

I have been using VisualSVN Server (version 3.9.7). Recently one of the SVN repositories is somehow corrupted and I would like to delete the repository and its database from the filesystem. However, I get the following error when I try to delete the repository:

```
Can't remove directory '<PATH_TO_REPOSITORY>\db\revprops\0': The directory is not empty.
```

I also see the following message on the VisualSVN Server control panel when I try to click on the repository name:

```
Unable to access repository
Failed to load module for FS type 'bdb'
```

I tried to manually delete the repository from the VisualSVN Server PowerShell after stopping the services; however, received the following error:

```
Confirm
The item at E:\REPOSITORY\TURBO_CORRUPTED has children and the Recurse parameter was not
specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to
continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): A
rmdir : The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
At line:1 char:1
+ rmdir .\TURBO_CORRUPTED
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (E:\REPOSITORY\TURBO_CORRUPTED:String) [Remove-
   Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS E:\REPOSITORY>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade the server to a supported version and see if it helps. [Version 3.9.x is not supported](https://www.visualsvn.com/company/news/visualsvn-server-3.9-end-of-support) starting from December 31, 2019. Current version is [5.1.x](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/).

Note that you can also remove the repository <PATH_TO_REPOSITORY> using Windows File Explorer.

### Update 1

I see the following error:

> rmdir : The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

This error can indicate hardware problems with your disk. Did you run [`chkdsk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk?tabs=event-viewer)?

You need to check the health of your disk and replace it if its faulty.

Comment: I tried deleting the repository from the file explorer but it didn't work.

Comment: I also added a new content to the original post. Could you please check it?

Comment: @yildizabdullah The error is`rmdir : The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable`. I guess that your disk is broken and has to be replaced. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I am currently backing up the existing repositories. After that I will try to run `chkdsk`.